# Django serializer not returning all fields

Tags: python, django, serialization

My serializer is not returning all fields from the model. Just the nested serializer.

**serializer.py**

```
class IndicatorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):       
    class Meta:
        model = Indicator

class QuoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Quote

class VWAPSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    vwap = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Quote
        fields = ('date','open','high','low','close','vwap',)

    def get_vwap(self, obj):
        indicators = Indicator.objects.filter(quote__in = obj)
        return IndicatorSerializer(indicators,many=True).data
```

**views.py**

```
def get_vwap(request):
    """
    List all vwap for a date
    """
    quotes = Quote.objects.filter(date__gt = '2016-05-05')
    serializer = VWAPSerializer(quotes)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

**models.py**

```
class Quote(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    symbol = models.ForeignKey(Symbol, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    open = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    high = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    low = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    close = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    last = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    prevclose = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    tottrdqty = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    tottrdval = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    total_trades = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        index_together = [
                ["symbol", "date"],
            ]

class Indicator(models.Model):
    quote = models.ForeignKey(Quote, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    indicator = models.ForeignKey(IndicatorDefinition, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('quote', 'indicator')
```

**Response**

```
"vwap": [
        {
            "id": 311743,
            "value": "1188.98",
            "quote": 77437,
            "indicator": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 311742,
            "value": "1185.52",
            "quote": 77437,
            "indicator": 2
        },
```

**Output of**
ser = VWAPSerializer()
    print(repr(ser))

```
VWAPSerializer():
    date = DateField(allow_null=True, required=False)
    open = DecimalField(allow_null=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=15, required=False)
    high = DecimalField(allow_null=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=15, required=False)
    low = DecimalField(allow_null=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=15, required=False)
    close = DecimalField(allow_null=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=15, required=False)
    vwap = SerializerMethodField()
```

I dont know if this helps i see this in the logs

```
VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [name] in u'<RegexURLResolver <RegexURLPattern list> (admin:admin) ^admin/>'
[DEBUG 2017-02-05 18:59:47,163] base.py [:929] _resolve_lookup: Exception while resolving variable 'name' in template 'unknown'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/avgeorge/trader/python/amrapali/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 907, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [name] in u'<RegexURLResolver <RegexURLPattern list> (admin:admin) ^admin/>
```

What im looking for is a set of given quotes to return all the quote information (as per the model) and also the VWAP data as a nested list for each quote. I hope that makes sense. Im not sure what Im doing wrong and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your `QuoteSerializer` in your `IndicatorSerializer`. See `django-rest-framework`'s [documentation on nested relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).

Comment: Thanks Raphael, Im using VWAPSerializer on the Quote model and in that I have the IndicatorSerializer.

Comment: Yes, but your `VWAPSerializer` only has one field that returns the `IndicatorSerializer`'s return value, and the latter does not do a nested serialization of `Quote`.

Comment: What I want is a list of quotes with nested vwap information not vwap with nested quotes.. Sorry if that was not clear from my question, i can edit it if necessary.

Comment: You specified `fields` with only `vwap`. You've excluded all other fields

Comment: Thanks, thats what I also did and have edited the question to show it. I thought the Model serializers automatically included all the fields by default. I have explicitly added them now but the response is the same. I have also edited the question to show the output of print serializer.